# DSolveValueNew - A leftover from the development of Wolfram Mathematica14.0?

Tags: differential-equations, bugs

I found that when you type DSolveValue a suggestion for DSolveValueNew appears. It looks that it is a leftover from the development of version 14.[image]

Comment: This gives us something to look forward to in version 15 !